# Add Buttons in a dynamically generated Table with JS

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, togglebutton

I am quite new to JS and I am facing the following problem.

I have a web site in my machine that I run locally. The little code in HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <h1>Json</h1>
    <br/>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="concept_list">
        <tr>
            <th>Buttons</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>color</th>
            <th>fingerprint</th>
            <th>hits</th>
            <th>ENGLISH</th>
            <th>FRENCH</th>
            <th>GERMAN</th> 
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

This creates basically the headers of a table.

I want to read JSON files locally in my computer and add data to the table.
I use a script as follows

```
<script >
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON("pvmodule.json", function(data){
var concept_list= '';

$.each(data, function(key, value){
    concept_list += '<tr>';
    concept_list += '<td>'+"HERE I WANT TO INSERT A TOGGLE BUTTON"+'</td>';
    concept_list += '<td>'+value.name+'</td>';
    concept_list += '<td>'+value.color+'</td>';
    concept_list += '<td>'+value.fingerprint+'</td>';
    concept_list += '<td>'+value.hits+'</td>';
    concept_list += '<td>'+value.EN+'</td>';
    concept_list += '<td>'+value.DE+'</td>';
    concept_list += '<td>'+value.FR+'</td>';
    concept_list += '</tr>';
});
$('#concept_list').append(concept_list);
  });
});

</script>
```

In the JS code above I want to insert a button in the first cell of the table in every row. (where i wrote "HERE I WANT TO ADD A TOGGLE BUTTON")
How do I dynamically add those buttons?

The intention being to add up in a field at the end of the web site all the values of the cells where the toggle buttons were clicked by the user.

Comment: Do you want to add one type of button or do you have a number of buttons to choose from some whare?

Comment: I use bootstrap to add buttons. But how a button looks like its a minor thing. The important thing for me as beginner is how to add the buttons and how to refer to them i.e. when clicking a button then add text in a field at the end

Answer (score 2):

```
concept_list += '<td>'+"HERE I WANT TO INSERT A TOGGLE BUTTON"+'</td>';
```

this should be

```
concept_list += '<td><button type="button>Click me</button></td>';
```

Refer [Button on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp)

Comment: It works. But how do I distinguish one button from each other for afterwards looping through them?

Comment: distinguish ? they will be in different rows. else you can put variable name or may value.name instead of CLick Me

Answer (score 0):

Add class first:

```
concept_list += '<td class="clickMe">'+"HERE I WANT TO INSERT A TOGGLE BUTTON"+'</td>';
```

Then use JQ to add button dynamically:

```
$(document).on('click','.clickMe',function(e){
$(this).html('<button>Hi</button>');
});
```